# The Node.js interface passed the Set-Cookie parameter, but since the browser made an HTTP request, document.cookie cannot retrieve the data

Tags: javascript

### Background:

My server is using Node.js, Express, and includes tools such as CORS, express-session, and connect-mongo. It utilizes HTTP requests. However, the browser is unable to retrieve cookies from the Set-Cookie response in the interface.

I am currently learning to use Node.js, and I want to implement cookie + session login session control. However, I have been troubled by the browser cookie issue for a long time. Thank you very much for your answer.

Additionally: My English is not good.

---

Image One: My Node.js interface has already returned the cookie.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO0Qx.png)

```js
var express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')
...
var app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(session({
  name: 'sid',
  secret: 'akh999',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: true, 
  store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/usersList'
  }),
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    sameSite: 'None',
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6,
  } 
}))

// --------------------------------------------------

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    ...
    req.session.text = 'xxx'
    req.session.user = userName
});
```

---

Image Two: My browser cannot obtain the cookie, and document.cookie also cannot retrieve it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEo5S.png)

```js
// vue3 
console.log(document.cookie) // no Data
```

=============================================

The solution I tried:

1. Cookie settings: httpOnly: false, sameSite: 'None'.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTyK8.png)

```js
app.use(session({
  ...
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    sameSite: 'None',
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6,
  } 
}))
```

2. I attempted to obtain an HTTPS certificate using SSL, but I am using a local server with 127.0.0.1. I tried to apply for HTTPS, but without success.
3. I set `withCredentials: true`, but encountered an error. I attempted to use the request header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1`, but it still didn't work.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBM10.png)

```js
// vue3
axios.post(url, parameters, {withCredentials: true,});

// ==============================

// nodejs
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1');
```

=============================================

The above are some of the solutions I tried, but I still can't retrieve cookies in the browser.

Additionally: my browser is running at 127.0.0.1:80, while the Node server is at 127.0.0.1:3000.

Thank you once again.

Comment: Share code and not pictures of code. Also please remove the chinese translations, your english is good!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about the functionality of this website. This is my first time using it. I've added code snippets, but I'm not sure how to correctly insert images.

Comment: The port number is part of the identity of the host. The same host but two separate port numbers are two separate sources as far as CORS rules are concerned.

Comment: Yes, I used the 'const cors = require('cors');' package to handle cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) issues.

I have seen 'set-cookie' in the response content of the interface, but I cannot retrieve the cookie through 'document.cookie'.

Comment: Please check in the http response from the network tab of the browser if the cookie is returned to ensure no issue with web app code.

Comment: Yes, 'Set-Cookie' is included in the 'Response Headers', but the browser still cannot access the cookie, which has been troubling me for a long time.

Comment: Please don't add any language other than English